# Calling extended's class method from parent class with extended class keeping instances of parent's variables

Tags: java

I'm implementing a visitor pattern for a particular domain, where I have some `BaseVisitor`, ie:

```
public class BaseVisitor {
    someC someInstance;

    visitA(...) {
        ...
    }

    visitB(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and a class that changes one particular functionality, `ExtendedVisitor`, ie:

```
public class ExtendedVisitor extends BaseVisitor {    
    visitA(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This `ExtendedVisitor` has a different implementation of `visitA`.

What I want to do is that when I'm in `visitB` of `BaseVisitor`, in special case I want to use the method of the `ExtendedVisitor` (`visitA`) as opposed to the regular `visitA` of the `BaseVisitor` itself. This works fine, ie.:

```
visitB(...) {
    if (...)
        new ExtendedVisitor().visitA();
    else
        visitA();
}
```

Now obviously, in the `BaseVisitor` there are many `visit` methods, and so the `visitA` of `ExtendedVisitor` will call them (ie. the original implementation of those methods - in `BaseVisitor`). The problem is that at this point I lost the instance of `someInstance` (ie. it is `null`). Is there a way for the two classes to share the variables? Ie. let the child use parent's variables?

Comment: Hi you are extending the BaseVisitor , so you can have access to instance variable of the BaseVisitor until you mark them as private.

Comment: This is not how inheritance and overriding works in Java. If you want to call from `visitB` the overridden version of `visitA()` in `ExtendedVisitor` then you just call `visitA()`. From the base class, you cannot even call the original version anymore (you can call `super.visitA()` from `ExtendedVisitor` though). So your `visitB` method becomes: `void visitB() { visitA(); }`. That's it.

Comment: For convenience BS = BaseVisitor, ES = ExtendedVisitor. BS' visitB calls ES's visitA, in ES' visitA and in the visitA I call e.g. visitC, this visitC is not implemented in ES and so it will go back to BS's implementation of visitC. However, at this point my someInstance is `null`.

Comment: That's because you do `new ExtendedVisitor().visitA()` - you created a new instance that doesn't have a value for `someInstance`. Don't do that. Just call `visitA()`

Comment: But I want to call visitA of the ES from the BS. ES doesn't have implementation of visitB. Ie. if some condition is met, call ES's visitA, if the condition is not met, call regular visitA. This all happens in BaseVisitor. I know I should not be using `new ExtendedVisitor(). ...` but I'm not sure how else to call ES's visitA properly?

Comment: Please read up on Java inheritance first. "ES doesn't have implementation of visitB" wrong. "ES" extends "BS" so it inherits visitB from BS.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling to new ExtendedVisitor() you are creating a new instance of that class and of course someInstance will be null. You could create a constructor like

```
public ExtendedVisitor(someC someInstance ){
   this.someInstance = someInstance
}
```

But it doesn't sound a great idea...

With your design you are forcing your parent class to know the functionality of its children classes. I see a coupling issue here. Probably you should rethink your code and use inheritance and polimorfism in a better way.